# Angular : como atualizar a variável no html automaticamente quando o valor da mesma for alterada no arquivo .ts?

Tags: angular, ionic

Eu tenho uma variável que recebe valor quando a página renderiza, e ele parece corretamente no template. Entanto se eu alterar o valor dela com a página já carregada o valor no .ts fica atualizando (conferido com console.log) mas no html permanece sem mudança.

HTML:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let linhacred of linha" style="font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;">
<h5>Nome: {{linhacred.nome}}</h5>
</ion-list>
```

TS:

```
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let str = Object.entries(dados).map(([key, val]) => `${key}=${val}`).join('&');
    this.http.post(this.apiUrl, str, options).subscribe(data => {
      const obj = (data as any);
      const obj_json = JSON.parse(obj._body);
      this.linha_credito = obj_json;
      this.global.gotoFinalView(this.linha_credito);
      console.log(this.linha_credito);
      this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab3']);
```

Comment: Olá. Aonde no seu TS está a variável linha? Seria a linha_credito? Use o  ChangeDetectorRef para detectar as mudanças do TS e renderizar na tela. Ao final da função que atualiza os dados, chame o "this.cdr.detectChanges()". Mais sobre: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: nesse seu ts vc não está mudando a propriedade linha

Comment: @GesielRosa Eu colei aqui o TS da página que envia a informação para outra tela (Que é a então exibida e que possui a variavel linha mencionada por voce. Ainda não consegui resolver o problema com a função mencionada, pdoeria me auxiliar ainda?

Segue TS da página citada:

export class Tab3Page {

  linha: any;
  constructor(private global: GlobalProvider, private router: Router) {
    this.retorna_simulacao();
  }
  public retorna_simulacao(){
    this.linha = this.global.getDestn();
    console.log(this.linha);
    this.todas_simulacoes = this.linha;  
  }

}